# Get filename without extension, textmade bundle editor

Tags: textmate, code-snippets

Thought this might work:

```
${TM_FILENAME/(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)/}
```

But it's giving me this error:

```
Error Parsing Snippet

line 1:257: expecting regexp options, found ''
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My original goal was to get rid of the .js extension, and this works like a charm.

```
${TM_FILENAME/[\.js]+$//}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here a solution to cut off general file extension

```
${TM_FILENAME/(.*)[.](.*)/$1/g}
```